# PHP in Apache: putenv has no effect

Tags: php, environment-variables

PHP running in Apache:

```
if (! putenv ('PATH=/my/path:'.getenv('PATH')))
    print 'putenv failed';
else
    print getenv("PATH");
```

This prints `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`, the path I specified isn't there. Why not?

Comment: Are you really doing the `getenv()` in the same script as the `putenv()`? Then it should work. If you're expecting the change to persist between different scripts, that's not how environment variables work. The environment is inherited by child processes, they don't propagate back to the parent process.

Comment: Definitely in the same script. Consecutive lines, even.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I'm using NGINX, not Apache, but I don't think that should make a difference once you're inside PHP.

Answer (score 0):

On Apache, you need to use `apache_setenv()`:

```
apache_setenv('PATH', '/my/path:' . getenv('PATH'));
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-setenv.php